# Castle Windsor: Exception thrown when resolving Component with LifeStyleScoped

Tags: castle-windsor, castle

I have a three components: A, B and C.

They are registrered in the following manners:

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
  public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
  {
    container.Register(Component.For<IA>().ImplementedBy<A>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IB>().UsingFactoryMethod(Resolve).LifestyleScoped());
    container.Register(Component.For<IC>().ImplementedBy<C>().LifestyleScoped());
  }

  private static IUnitOfWork Resolve(IKernel kernel)
  {
    IA a = kernel.Resolve<IA>();
    B b = new B(a);
    kernel.ReleaseComponent(a);
    return b;
  }
}
```

When I Resolve C I do it in the following manner:

```
public void Test()
{
  using (ContainerAccessor.Instance.IocContainer.BeginScope())
  {
    using (IB b = containerAccessor.Instance.IocContainer.Resolve<IB>())
    {
      IC c = ContainerAccessor.Instance.IocContainer.Resolve<IC>();
      ...
      b.Commit();

      return result;
    }
}
```

The **first time** I access it, an exception is thrown : "InvalidOperationException: Scope was not available. Did you forget to call container.BeginScope()?".

I partly solve it by wrapping the content of the Resolve method with a `using (kernel.BeginScope) { ... }`.
I said it was partly solved because when I put a breakpoint in the resolve method, it still throws the exception the first time I access it.
Does someone have an idea of what is happening here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of Castle.Windsor are you using? And can you be a bit more specific about what you are accessing? Which line fails?